# Why do flagged / unread emails appear multiple times in an Outlook / gmail / IMAP setup?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail-imap

When using Outlook to retrieve gmail over IMAP, flagged or unread items appear multiple times (2 or 3) in my inbox. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer after trawling through a number of Microsoft support posts. Reposting here, as SU is a more user-friendly retrieval system.

This is due to the way that gmail treats labels. When items are flagged in Outlook, they are marked as "starred" and "important" on gmail. Gmail exports this subset of email as a separate IMAP folder, which Outlook consumes. The message then appears multiple times.

The solution is to browse to gmail.com, go to settings --> Labels, and untick "show in IMAP" for the "starred" and "important" labels. It may also be possible to simply unsubscribe from those folders in Outlook (I haven't tried).

Linked question (tasks not email): [Gmail & Outlook 2007 (Flagging Gmail in Outlook creating 4 tasks)](https://superuser.com/q/541632/406310)

Comment: I also had to go under Settings -> **Forwarding and POP/IMAP** and select **Enable IMAP** to get the `Show in IMAP` checkboxes to appear. Not sure how Outlook was reading Gmail without that enabled.